Python: duplicated row with condition in dataframe
we have this dataframe:



ID
Dest
Change




RL1
Z32
Yes


RL1
Z32
No


RL1
Z33
Yes


RL1
Z33
Yes


RL2
Z32
Yes



And I need to identify that "Dest" Z32 is duplicated with the condition of having "No" in column "Change" in its group of ID (independent treatment for RL1, RL2, ...).
So, group by ID, find duplicated rows by Dest with condition of Change = No
So, output desired:



ID
Dest
Change
Dup_with_condition_in_its_group_ID




RL1
Z32
Yes
Yes


RL1
Z32
No
No


RL1
Z33
Yes
No


RL1
Z33
Yes
No


RL2
Z32
Yes
No



Data to reproduce:
data = {
    "ID": ["RL1", "RL1", "RL1", "RL1", "RL2"],
    "Dest": ["Z32", "Z32", "Z33", "Z33", "Z32"],
    "Change": ["Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes"]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

Thanks.
I have tried identify duplicated without conditions, buy I need to add the AND condition to identify duplicated rows.
